# How can I cap calculation speed?

Tags: performance-tuning, kernel, system-performance, resource-management

Sorry if I wasn't able to find an existing answer!

I'm trying out Mathematica, and was running through some sample problems at night. My roommate is sleeping, and my computer fan can get decently loud.

Is there a way to simply slow down how fast Mathematica tries to execute a cell? I want it to be *less* efficient, so that at any point it won't be drawing enough resources to need such measures. I'm aware that my cell will take longer to evaluate, it isn't too pressing.

Thanks for any help! Mathematica looks truly powerful!

Comment: On Linux one can change the priority of the process with `renice` command (https://www.computerhope.com/unix/renice.htm). The information on a process can be retrieved with `ps` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/what-is-a-command-to-find-priority-of-process-in-linux)

Comment: **My roommate is sleeping, and my computer fan can get decently loud.** I do not know if there is a way to control this from Mathematica. But if you on windows, you can lower the process priority. on windows that is 10 the lowest and 0 the highest. Go to task manager , then Details tab and then Set priority. Do this for the Mathematica kernel process.